# Transmageddon xvid codec missing

Tags: codecs

According to the Info section of Transmageddon in Ubuntu Software Center, xvid is included in the codec options. But when I installed the software, it's not there.

Here is a screenshot of Transmageddon's codec options:

[image]

**THE QUESTION:** Is there a way to bring the xvid codec back? and How?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have `libxvidcore4` installed?

Comment: It seems already installed. I ran "sudo apt-get install libxvidcore4" and the terminal even says I have the newest package.
Sorry man. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER:**

After researching on other sites, I've discovered that the version of Transmageddon available in Ubuntu Software Center is outdated (v0.25) and the latest is v1.3.

So I bumped into this very helpful site ([LINK](http://www.sysads.co.uk/2014/07/install-transmageddon-video-converter-1-3-ubuntu-14-04/)), and followed the instructions on how to install the updated version of Transmageddon.

Here is a screenshot with xvid codec:
[http://i.imgur.com/6pOMZke.png](https://i.imgur.com/6pOMZke.png)